# PHP- getting the value of a cell for use with an api

Tags: php, mysql, api, steam

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm pretty new at PHP.

So first, here is what I'm trying to do:

I am pulling information from MYSQL and displaying the info on a page. specifically this bit:

```
while($rowsID = mysql_fetch_assoc($sIDD))
{
echo '<tr>';
foreach($rowsID as $key => $cell){
    print '<td>'.$cell.'</td>';
}
```

This works fine and displays the info I want.

The information from that cell, I want to plug into:

```
$sid = $rowsID['steamID'];
$key = '<yoink>';
$slink =file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=' .        $key . '&steamids=' . $sid . '&format=json');
$myarray = json_decode($slink, true);
print '<img src=';
print $myarray['response']['players'][0]['avatarmedium'];
print '>'; `
```

This does not work. It won't pull the actual number from the cell and put it into $sid. I've at a loss here. I'm googled for days, and most of my code is frankenstiened from bits I've found around here, so I'm not even sure I'm on the right track. I hope I've clearly explained my problem and provided enough info. Thanks for any help.

The full code:

```
<?php
$hostname = "";   // eg. mysql.yourdomain.com (unique)
$username = "";   // the username specified when setting-up the database
$password = "";   // the password specified when setting-up the database
$database = "";   // the database name chosen when setting-up the database (unique)

$imgR =  "<td><img src='/images/red-dot2.png".$cell['red-dot2.png']."'></td>";
$imgG =  "<td><img src='/images/green-dot2.png".$cell['green-dot2.png']."'></td>";
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
// Line 10
$_GET['id'];
$name = $_GET['id'];

$link = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

$sql = "SELECT Members.PID, Members.ID, Members.Steam_Name, Members.SG_ID\n"
    . "FROM Members WHERE Members.PID = '$name%' ";

//Line 20
$gas = "SELECT Giveaways.title, Giveaways.cv, Members_1.Page, Giveaways.B, Giveaways.entries\n"
    . "FROM Members_1 INNER JOIN (Members INNER JOIN Giveaways ON Members.SG_ID = Giveaways.giver) ON Members_1.SG_ID = Giveaways.status\n"
    . "WHERE (((Members.PID)='$name'))";

$cvGiven = "SELECT Members.PID, Sum(Giveaways.cv) AS SumOfcv\n"
    . "FROM Members INNER JOIN Giveaways ON Members.SG_ID = Giveaways.giver\n"
    . "GROUP BY Members.PID\n"
    . "HAVING (((Members.PID)=$name)) ";

//Line 30
$winResults = "SELECT Giveaways.title, Members_1.Page, Giveaways.cv, Giveaways.B, Giveaways.entries\n"
    . "FROM Members INNER JOIN (Members_1 INNER JOIN Giveaways ON Members_1.SG_ID = Giveaways.giver) ON Members.SG_ID = Giveaways.status\n"
    . "WHERE (((Members.PID)=$name)) ";

$cvWon = "SELECT Members.PID, Sum(Giveaways.cv) AS SumOfcvW\n"
    . "FROM Members INNER JOIN Giveaways ON Members.SG_ID = Giveaways.status\n"
    . "GROUP BY Members.PID\n"
    . "HAVING (((Members.PID)=$name)) ";

$sID = "SELECT Members.ID\n"
    . "FROM Members\n"
    . "WHERE (((Members.PID)=$name))";

$get = "SELECT Members.PID, Members.SG_ID\n"
    . "FROM Members";

//Line 40

$result = mysql_query($sql,$link) or die("Unable to select: ".mysql_error());
$result2 = mysql_query($gas,$link) or die("Unable to select: ".mysql_error());
$cvTotal = mysql_query($cvGiven,$link) or die("Unable to select: ".mysql_error());
$cvTotalW = mysql_query($cvWon,$link) or die("Unable to select: ".mysql_error());
$wins = mysql_query($winResults,$link) or die("Unable to select: ".mysql_error());
$sIDD = mysql_query($sID,$link) or die("Unable to select: ".mysql_error());
$getN= mysql_query($get,$link) or die("Unable to select: ".mysql_error());


if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

if (!$result2) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}
if (!$cvTotal) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}
if (!$sIDD) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

if (!$getN) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

//Line 60
if (!$cvTotalW) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}
if (!$wins) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////Start Structure//////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//Display name
echo '<h2>[[Breadcrumbs?showHomeCrumb = 0  ]]</h2>';

//Display Steam ID
$sid = $rowsID['steamID'];
$key = '';

   $slink = file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=' . $key . '&steamids=' . $sid . '&format=json');
   $myarray = json_decode($slink, true);
    print $myarray['response']['players'][0]['avatarmedium'];
   // print '>'; 
print $sid;


echo '<table>';

while($rowsID = mysql_fetch_assoc($sIDD))
{
echo '<tr>';
    foreach($rowsID as $key => $cell){
        print '<th>Steam ID:</th>'.'<td>'.$cell.'</td>';

    }
echo'</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

//CV totals
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($cvTotal);
$sum = $row['SumOfcv'];
$rowW = mysql_fetch_assoc($cvTotalW);
$sumW = $rowW['SumOfcvW'];

//Start CV table
echo '<div class=cv>';
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>Total CV Given:</td>';
echo '<td> $'. number_format ($sum,2). '</td>';
echo '<tr>';
echo "<td>Total CV Won:</td>";
echo '<td> $'. number_format ($sumW,2). '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo "</tr>\n\n";
echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';




//Start Giveaways List
echo '<h3>Giveaways</h3>';
echo '<div class=llamatable>';
echo"<table>\n";
echo'<th>Game</th><th>CV</th><th>Winner</th><th></th><th>NB?</th><th>Entries</th>';


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {



    print "<tr>\n";
      //Is it a bundle?
      foreach($row as $key => $cell){
       if ($key == 'B' && strpos($cell,'1') !== false){
         $cell = str_replace('1',$cell,$imgR);
        } 
        elseif($key == 'B' && $cell == "0"){
            $cell= $imgG;
       }
      //Set cv format
       if($key == 'cv'){
         $cell= '$'. number_format ($cell,2); //Line 80
        }
        //set breaks if multiple winners
       if (strpos($cell,',') !== false){
         $cell= str_replace(',','<br />',$cell);
        }
       if($key == 'status' && strpos($cell, $nameName)){
         $cell = $test;
       }        
        echo"<td>$cell</td>\n";

    }


    print "</tr>\n";


    //print "</br>\n";
}// End Giveaways list
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

print "</table>\n";
print "</div>";


//Start Wins List
echo '<h3>Wins</h3>';
echo '<div class=llamatable>';
//$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($results);
echo"<table>\n";
echo'<th>Game</th><th>Contributor</th><th>cv</th><th></th><th>NB?</th><th>Entries</th>';


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($wins)) {

    print "<tr>\n";
      //Is it a bundle?
      foreach($row as $key => $cell){
       if ($key == 'B' && strpos($cell,'1') !== false){
         $cell = str_replace('1',$cell,$imgR);
        } //Line 110
        elseif($key == 'B' && $cell == "0"){
            $cell= $imgG;
       }
      //Set cv amount
       if($key == 'cv'){
         $cell= '$'. number_format ($cell,2);
        }
        //set breaks if multiple winners
       if (strpos($cell,',') !== false){
         $cell= str_replace(',','<br />',$cell);
        }
        echo"<td>$cell</td>\n";

    }
print "</tr>\n";



}// End wins list
print "</table>\n";
    echo "</div>";



//echo '</table>';
//echo '</div>';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

I realize the code is probably a disaster, I plan on cleaning it up once I have it working and understand more fully what I'm looking at. I've copie and patched together code from a lot of different sources, as well as attempted my own. Don't hate me. :-)

Comment: Oh, it does work properly If I plug the actual number in for the $sid value. but I can't do that manually for each person due to the way the site is coded.

Comment: show the actual code. we have no idea how your two code snippets are related? Are they in the same script and run during the same http request? or are they in two completely separate scripts and you want a user to click on the `<td>$cell</td>` from the first bit to trigger the second snippet?

Comment: Where did you put `$sid = $rowsID['steamID'];`? Is it in te while loop? Otherwise you will need to add another key to assign id

Comment: You keep referring to "that cell". You're displaying an entire table, which cell do you want to plug into the PHP code?

Comment: What I suspect you need to do is make each row or cell a link, and the URL parameters should include the `steamID` of the associated player.

Comment: its not clear at all, edit your question a little more

Comment: Sorry, I didn't not include all of the code because it is a complete mess (no clue what I'm doing, basically learning PHP by doing this). I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems. First, and foremost, you are using the `$rowsID` variable before it has data.

```
$sid = $rowsID['steamID']; 
        ^-------- You don't assign this a value until 12 lines later, here:

while($rowsID = mysql_fetch_assoc($sIDD))
```

Second, you should **not** use the `mysql_*` functions. Instead look into [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) as a replacement for the *deprecated* [mysql](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) functions

Third, **SANITIZE YOUR INPUT**. You are taking the value in `$_GET['id']` and passing it directly to your queries. Hello, [Little Bobby Tables.](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Solving those problems should get you on your way.

A few things you may want to consider improving:

- If I am reading your queries correctly, you are querying based on player name, right? What happens if two people have the name `Llama`?
- If you are going to be querying the Steam API for each user, build a string of profile IDs separated by a comma and then pass all of those (up to 100) to the `steamids` variable when you make your API call. This reduces the number of round trips you have to make to Valve's servers
- I don't know your database structure, but several of those queries look like they can be combined with some fancy SQL. If you know more complicated SQL, it'd be a good idea to reduce the number of calls to the database for performance improvements.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful response!
I was able to get it to work by moving the api call to the inside of the while loop and changing rowsID['steamID'] to $cell.
I will look into the mysqli. I have been using my databases' built-in php translator to convert my sql statements, and have just been using what it gives me.

As far as sanitizing, the $GET['id'] pulls the page id from the url, which I create manually for each person and store it in a column in the database, so it's always just a two digit number. Is that still an issue?

Thanks again!

Comment: Yes it is. The URL in the browser will look like this: `http://example.com/?name=100`. What if someone modifies the URL to read `http://example.com/?name=';drop table users;--`? Just because you create the URL, doesn't mean it's safe. A user can go up to the URL bar and change it to whatever they want it to say.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll start looking into how to sanitize. Thanks again!